# PayPal payments to a specific email using Python

Tags: paypal

It is required to write a script in Python, with the help of which it will be possible to transfer funds from one PayPal account to another PayPal account.

input parameters:

1. Sender's e-mail
2. E-mail of the recipient
3. transfer amount.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For PayPal Checkout payments, the sender's email is determined by what they sign into or pay as a guest with. That payer email is not an input parameter prior to their reaching the PayPal Checkout, although one can be pre-filled by your system if already known--but cookies from previous logins might take precedence. *(If you need to send money from a specific account *without* a payer signing into their sender account, that account's owner could [request access to PayPal Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/#link-getaccesstopaypalpayouts), which may or may not be granted depending on the business need and use case.)*

For such PayPal Checkout payments to be sent to a specified recipient email, [set a `payee` object in the purchase_units](https://%20https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/) when creating the order (which happens on button click).

A server integration to create and capture the order via API with a backend is not required, but certainly recommended for a robust integration that acts on the API capture response. The [Checkout-Python-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK) can be used to implement two routes on your server (one for create order, and one for capturing a given order ID. The client-side approval flow to pair with those two server routes is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server.